# Recording track log in QGIS

Tags: qgis, route, tracklog

I am using QGIS to record field data and also meandering field transects.  When I was using ArcGIS I could turn on the tracklog function and a shapefile could be created of automatically generated points, and the recording interval could be varied by the user.

QGIS tracks your movement on screen with a red line, but it is not recorded as a tracklog.  Is there a way/plug in that performs a tracklog recording task in QGIS?

Comment: Are you using the GPS Information Panel?